# How to count the elements in a column of arrays?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to count the number of elements in `FavouriteCities` column in the following DataFrame.

```
+-----------------+
| FavouriteCities |
+-----------------+
|   [NY, Canada]  |
+-----------------+
```

The schema is as follows:

```
scala> data.printSchema
root
|-- FavouriteCities: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Expected output should be something like,

```
+------------+-------------+
|  City      |      Count  |
+------------+-------------+
| NY         |      1      |
| Canada     |      1      |
+------------+-------------+
```

I have tried using the `agg()` and `count()` but like the following, but it fails to extract individual elements from the array and tries to find the most common set of elements in the column.

```
data.agg(count("FavouriteCities").alias("count"))
```

Can someone please guide me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match schema you've shown:

```
scala> val data = Seq(Tuple1(Array("NY", "Canada"))).toDF("FavouriteCities")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [FavouriteCities: array<string>]
scala> data.printSchema
root
 |-- FavouriteCities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Explode:

```
val counts = data
  .select(explode($"FavouriteCities" as "City"))
  .groupBy("City")
  .count
```

and aggregate:

```
import spark.implicits._
scala> counts.as[(String, Long)].reduce((a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b)
res3: (String, Long) = (Canada,1)
```

Comment: Why don't you `sort` and `head` rather than `reduce`?

Comment: Cool. This worked. I have used sort and head, which felt easier :) Thanks guys!